# SQL Server query: average progression of users steps

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a user table and a table which stores the users step count each day.

I need a T-SQL query that shows the average users steps progression over time, and find out if the average user all together makes more steps over time.

In other words: I want to show if a user makes more steps since the first step entry (trend, in a graph later).

I don't really know how to project this in a query

My tables are

Users:

| UserId |
| --- |
| Int |

StepsHistory:

| StepsHistoryId | UserId | DateStepsMade | StepsCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Int | Int | Date | Int |

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help

Comment: IMHO dont mix singular and plural names for tables.

Answer (score 0):

I simple GROUP BY using the AVG aggregate should get you the average steps per user. Joining with the Users table will cover users who have done no steps

```
SELECT Users.UserId, ISNULL(AVG(StepsHistory.StepsCount), 0)
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN StepsHistory ON Users.UserId=StepsHistory.UserId
GROUP BY Users.UserId
```

You could add a UNION ALL to get the average for all users at the start of the list:

```
SELECT NULL, AVG(StepsHistory.StepsCount)
FROM StepsHistory
UNION ALL
SELECT Users.UserId, ISNULL(AVG(StepsHistory.StepsCount), 0)
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN StepsHistory ON Users.UserId=StepsHistory.UserId
GROUP BY Users.UserId
```